# AWS Aurora Adding Foreign Key Fails with Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, foreign-keys

The AWS Aurora docs indicate that it's MySQL 5.6 compliant.

I execute this:

```
    ALTER TABLE slave 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id(20)) 
     REFERENCES master(id);
```

It fails:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
 SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 

    ------------------------
    LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
    ------------------------
    2017-08-31 22:29:13 Error in foreign key constraint of table xxx:
    FOREIGN KEY (id(20)) REFERENCES master(id):
    Syntax error close to:
    (20)) REFERENCES master(id)
```

I verified that:

- The collation of `slave` is  `latin1_swedish_ci`.
- The collation of `master` is `latin1_swedish_ci`.
- The collation of `slave.id` is  `latin1_swedish_ci`.
- The collation of `master.id` is `latin1_swedish_ci`.
- The type of `slave.id` is `tinytext`.
- The type of `master.id` is `tinytext`.
- `master.id` is the PRIMARY KEY on `master`.
- The engine is InnoDB.

What is the syntax error?  My command seems to conform to the MySQL 5.6 documentation.

Comment: In MySQL, you cannot use prefixed indexes for foreign keys, so the (20) would not be allowed. (Which is the reason you cannot use foreign keys for blob/(tiny)text in MySQL).

Comment: In the MySQL 5.6 foreign keys docs: "The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).  That seems to indicate that foreign keys using strings is supported?

Comment: Yes, strings work with different max length (column type). But also mentioned in the link: *Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length.* `id(20)` is a prefixed index, so the `(20)` is not supported in MySQL. Since `id` is a pk in `master`, aurora seems (in contrast to MySQL) to support (tiny)text as a primary key, so maybe an unprefixed foreign key to it will work (I can't test that, but try without `(20)`. Or use varchar).

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks!  Now I see the distinction between TEXT/BLOB types and CHAR/VARCHAR types.  Simply using VARCHAR for my columns works for my foreign keys.  Post the answer and I'll accept it if you want the credit.